# What functional encryption scheme can be used to compute a linear function?

Tags: reference-request, functional-encryption

I am looking for a functional encryption scheme that can compute a linear function. I do not need to work with attributes.

All I want is to compute the result of a function $y = a*x+b$, where $x$ is the hidden value, which I don't want to reveal.

Comment: Can your linear function be represented as a matrix? If so, you might be able to get away with something simpler like inner-product encryption to multiply your matrix (i.e. evaluate your linear function) on a value (vector) in the message space.

Comment: By 'inner-product encryption' I mean an encryption which supports inner product computation on ciphertexts.

Comment: https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2008/49650145/49650145.pdf

Comment: Will the encryptor know what the linear function is? ​ (Just checking, as that would make it trivial.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @pg1989, the functionality I want to implement is like this : F : K x Z -> Z, K - the space of party's secret key, Z - the set of integers and the ciphertext space. In my case, K = Z.

Comment: @RickyDemer, please correct me if I am wrong : all I want to do is to use a secret value,  to obtain another value, which would be publicly known, and if the knowledge of the circuit does not reveal any information about my secret value, I guess it's fine for the encryptor to know the circuit. But, anyway, give me solutions for both situations and maybe I'll gain more insight about what I truly need.

Comment: Is the linear function the "secret value"? ​ ​

Comment: No, I want the function to output something of the form y = a * x + b, where x is the encrypted secret value. I don't know if the party secret key should be a or b, or maybe the solution is not functional encryption. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, the trivial solution is letting outer_encryption_(m) be ​ [prefixfree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)(inner_encryption_(m)) [||](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) linear_function_(m) . ​ ​ ​ If that doesn't work, then you should try clarifying what you're after. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​